# My reactJS app doesnt re renders when redux changes the state in store

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, reactive-programming

Iam new to learning Redux. 
When i write store.subscribe(render) my app compiles without errors but nothing shows up.
I've been following an **article**(https://medium.freecodecamp.org/understanding-redux-the-worlds-easiest-guide-to-beginning-redux-c695f45546f6) that beautifully explains redux but that subscribe part is just not working.
Any help in this regard will be very much appreciated.

I tried everything i could i even rebuilt the app but no luck.

[index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOKq9.png)

[./reducer/index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14zTu.png)

[./store/index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fETrs.png)

[App.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCay9.png)

Comment: why do you use store.subscribe ?? Instead ot use provider like this ``` <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,```

Comment: I'am new to redux and i was following this article >>>https://medium.freecodecamp.org/understanding-redux-the-worlds-easiest-guide-to-beginning-redux-c695f45546f6

Comment: use please react-redux, it is more cleaner and understandable and have no side effects when using redux with react. you can follow to this article: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-use-redux-in-reactjs-with-real-life-examples-687ab4441b85

Comment: I'am still in learning phase so i want to stick to simpler things first. Please review my codes and tell me where I went wrong :(

Comment: okay could you provide jsfiddle example not just images!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try changing line 17 of App.js from

```
<HelloWorld tech={this.state.tech}/>
```

to:

```
<HelloWorld tech={store.getState().tech}/>
```

Else, try putting a constructor into your App component:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    store.subscribe(() => {
      this.setState({
        tech: store.getState().tech
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you soooooo much 
Adding a constructor finally solved my problem.
Thank you very much once again ^_^

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a provider into your store to subscribe the changes.
For more details please check this link https://react-redux.js.org/api/provider

Please find the sample code for the store.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

import { App } from './App'
import createStore from './createReduxStore'

const store = createStore()

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Comment: but the article which i was following didn't mentioned any providers or something i followed everything that article taught. It was going well but then I encountered this issue. when i write render() my app shows up but it doesnt when i write store.subscribe() and the DOM doesn't update either with the new state in store.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import createStore.

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
```

Then you will need to make the store variable and pass in the reducer.

```
const store = createStore(yourReducer);
```

Then your reducer will look something like this.

```
const initState = {

}

const yourReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
    return state;
}

export default yourReducer
```

Comment: well that's exctly what i did and the state changes i verified it in console.log the only problem is my DOM is not re rendering when the state changes it simply goes blank when i user store.subscribe(render) in my index.js file